# Krull dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (xy)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> What is the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (xy)$?

I believe the only prime ideals of this ring are $(x,y),(x), (y)$. The supremum of all the heights is $1$ by the sequence $(x) \subset (x,y)$, so I would say that the Krull dimension is $1$, but I am not sure. Can someone tell me if this reasoning is correct? $0$ is not a prime ideal since $xy = 0$.

Comment: I do not think that your sentence is correct. For instance, $(x,y-1)$ is a prime ideal. However, are you ok with $\dim C[x] = 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$ correspond to the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $(xy)$. Thus as in the comment of Youngsu, $(x, y-1)$ is a prime ideal, and your conjecture is wrong.

The prime ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ that contains $(xy)$ must contains $x$ or $y$. We assume that $x\in I$, and that $(x)\subsetneq I$. Since $(x)$ is prime, the height of $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is at least 2. But $\mathrm{dim}\mathbb{C}[x,y]=2$. (It needs some conclusions about dimension of finitely generated algebra over a field. You can find these, for example, in the Ch.11 of Atiyah-Macdonald's book.) Therefore, $I$ must be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $I$ must have the form like $(x, y-b)$. But anyway, the Krull's dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$ is just equal to $1$.